# Thymeleaf silently fails when no value provided

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I’m working on a Spring project using thymeleaf for the templates. I’ve come into a situation where a placeholder value is not provided in the resolver context. In this case thymeleaf just replaces the placeholder with a blank and moves on.

Is there an option that will tell thymeleaf to throw an exception in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Not able to find any documentation on this, so I am assuming Thymeleaf does not support such a feature.